# Do Half height (low profile) truck bed cap/camper shells exist?

Tags: car-camping

I am about to purchase my first pickup truck (Chevy Colorado Zr2 Bison) and want to use it for camping and overlanding. I am looking for a truck cap or camper shell but with a lower profile height. Most truck bed caps are sold with a top that matches with the height of the main truck cab.

However, I want something that only goes as high as 1/2 the height between the top end of the bed and the drivers cabin. My intend is to put a roof top tent on top of the cab so that the cab plus roof top tent matches in height with the height of the drivers cabin. The reason is that I sometimes want to transport a kayak that is placed upside down on top of the roof top tent and the drivers cab.

So my question is: do low profile or half height to 2/3 height truck bed caps exist or would this have to be 100% custom? Ideally the low profile cap would have some smaller windows or air ducts because sometimes I would just like to crash in the truck bed for a night enroute the final destination in locations where it is not feasible to pop open the roof top tent.

Comment: There are certainly half-height bed racks (well, at least for my Tacoma). Some will work with a tonneau cover. I have not seen an enclosed one, but with some effort they could be at least enclosed with a soft top. Or something like the DiamondBack cover with rack mount?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your tips. I am aware of the racks but was so far hoping to get an enclosed cap. But as I have not seen any so far I am not sure whether going this route works. Otherwise I am thinking about the DiamondBack HD and put a rack on top just as you suggested.

Comment: I’m still thinking what I’ll do. I think the issue with a half-height enclosed cover is it would be really hard to get stuff in and out since it would be very cramped inside. You would need a full-bed slide or a complete drawer system. The other option is a trailer for the camping stuff.

Comment: I've seen some medium height lift covers, but they're not common. For the most part they seem to be full height or flat with optional bed rack on top of arbitrary height.

Comment: @Separatrix, do you recall the name of those medium height lift covers?

Comment: @MatthiasWolf, I was sure it was Mountain Top, but they only seem to do the flat cap and roller covers now.

Comment: ok, thanks for checking

Comment: Would something like this work? http://www.easygoandstow.com/Cap-to-Cover.html